# Java; int[] to int

Tags: java, arrays, integer

How would I convert an array of integers into an integer, but in a special way?

For example, how would I convert { 1, 9, 9, 0 } into 1990?

Comment: What is the expected behavior if any given array element is outside of the range `[0, 9]`? Is this homework? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This will work for any size integer array

```
int nums[] = { 1, 9, 9, 0 };

StringBuilder strNum = new StringBuilder();

for (int num : nums) 
{
     strNum.append(num);
}
int finalInt = Integer.parseInt(strNum.toString());
System.out.println(finalInt);
```

Comment: That converts to a `String`, not an integer.

Comment: adding an Integer.valueOf() at the bottom should do the trick.

Comment: This solution is more correct and general than restricting the numbers to single digits.

Comment: @Matt: That's not the point of exceptions. That is, exceptions are not a fix for lack-of-information. You could argue if you knew the correct data, an exception would be appropriate, but CustomerWasVague exception isn't a solution to anything.

Comment: You should change strNum to StringBuilder. [Concatenating Strings in a loop is a very bad idea.](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/bugDescriptions.html#SBSC_USE_STRINGBUFFER_CONCATENATION)

Answer (score 7):

```
int[] array = {1,9,9,0};
int result = 0;
for(int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) result += Math.pow(10,i) * array[array.length - i - 1];
System.out.println(result);
```

```
Output: 1990
```

Comment: Because this is a terrible solution for the reasons I and others have outlined on other posts, except this version is even less readable.

Comment: @Stefan: for all you know, this could be exactly the desired behavior (though I do agree that it's less elegant than the deleted one). Nothing in the question enables us to decide between this method and the string concatenation one.

Answer (score 5):

It is upsetting to see the unnecessarily complex solutions, involving `Math.pow`, `String` etc. Even regex and third party libraries make an appearance!

All you need is a loop and multiplication by 10:

```
int num = 0;
for (int a : arr) {
  num = 10*num + a;
}
```

This of course assumes that the elements of `arr` are in range 0-9; but then the correct behavior outside that case is undefined anyway.

It also assumes that the array's digits can be converted to an integer without overflow; but since the question asks about converting to an integer, overflow behavior is also undefined.

---

Note that you can handle the "element > 9" case in the similar way to the [string concatenation solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7170257/3788176) by working out how many digits you have to shift `num` by:

```
int num = 0;
for (int a : arr) {
  if (a < 0) throw new IllegalArgumentException();
  int i = a;
  do {
    num *= 10;
    i /= 10;
  } while (i != 0);
  num += a;
}
```

I don't think this is the most appropriate way to handle multiple digits in an element; at the very least the behaviour should be specified. I'm just pointing out that you don't need to resort to strings to handle it.

Comment: In my opinion, this is the most simple way which do not waste performance like double cast (from int to string and again to int)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure in Java, but in pseudo .NET code:

```
String value = "";
for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++)
{
    value += array[i]; // Build out the number as a string
}

int someInt = Integer.parseInt(value);
```

Comment: It's like you copy and pasted Shawn's answer directly, but you did it worse by not using the example data.

Comment: @Stefan Kendall heh. I was writing my answer while his posted-- but thanks for the comment.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you have digits in `Integer[]` instead of primitive `int[]` and have [Commons Lang Library](http://commons.apache.org/lang/) you may find following one liner useful

```
    Integer[] array = {1, 9, 9, 0 };
    System.out.println(Integer.valueOf(StringUtils.join(array)));
```

Or if the integer is too big to fit in `int` use `BigInteger`

```
    Integer[] piDigits = { 3, 1, 4, 1, 5, 9, 2, 6, 5, 3, 5, 8, 9, 7, 9, 3, 2,
            3, 8, 4, 6, 2, 6, 4, 3, 3, 8, 3, 2, 7, 9, 5, 0, 2, 8, 8, 4, 1,
            9, 7, 1, 6, 9, 3, 9, 9, 3, 7, 5, 1, 0, 5, 8, 2, 0, 9, 7, 4, 9,
            4, 4, 5, 9, 2, 3, 0, 7, 8, 1, 6, 4, 0, 6, 2, 8, 6 };
    System.out.println(new BigInteger(StringUtils.join(piDigits)));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use:

```
public void turnArrToInt(int x[]){
    for(int i = 0; i < x.length; i++){
        number += x[i]*Math.pow(10,x.length-i-1);
    }
```

This is how I implemented it. It takes each element, and if it is the first of the array it multiplies it by 10^(length of the array - 1 - theCurrentElement) and it adds all to the result. It works for all sizes. Basically multiplying the 100th by 100, 10th by 10 and so on.

For example: char = {1,2,3} would multiply 1 by 100 2 by 10 3 by 1 and get the sum of all and get 123.

Answer (score -1):

```
Arrays.toString(nums).replaceAll("\\D+","");
```